# C# Comparing Values from dynamic's

Tags: c#, dynamic

Today i tried an old project, in my company and got an error which makes me curious. The issue line looks something like this:

```
if((dynamic)com_list.GetIntValue() != (dynamic)container.GetEnumValue())
```

The exception shows clearly that you can't compare `Int32` with an `Enum`.

But i wonder, could this have ever worked, in some circumstance?

Are there changes in the `dynamic` Keyword which don't allow this anymore?

---

BTW, he also build this in the code like this:

```
if((dynamic)com_list.GetIntValue() != (dynamic)container.GetBooleanValue())
```

---

*I'm still confused, why somebody would put this kind of comparing into productiv code.*

Comment: Are you sure it ever worked? Are you sure the code actually executed at some point, successfully?

Comment: Nope. The product is shipped, but this part of code is not in use. And i'm now really confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The `dynamic` specification hasn't changed and I am pretty sure the evaluation in the compiler of such a trivial comparison didn't change overnight in one release to another. Most likely that code never worked.

Without additional cast from `enum` to `int` (or the other way around) it won't work.

Comment: Thank you. But i'm still confused, why somebody would put this kind of comparing into productiv code.

Comment: Good question. Why not ask the author? Probably some forgotten, untested code.

Comment: Most likely casting to dynamic was done just for the code to compile. Author was not bothered about if it will actually work or not.

Comment: That's the reason why i asked SO. The developer of this isn't anymore available to the company.

Comment: And it couldn't have something to with it, that the `com_list` object is an `COM` object, or?

Comment: Yes, but that would require a different casting. As I said, testing code.